# show multiple selected values of drop-down after submit if error comes on form

Tags: php, html

I have this drop-down and user can select multiple options ,how can i keep selected value on form after submit button, if error comes on form

```
<th align="right" style="width: 264px"><label id="lcell">*Preferred City for Relocation Work :</label></th>
<td><select  onchange="document.getElementById('cand_pref').style.display='none';" name="pcity[]" id="pcity" multiple="multiple" >
<?php 
$pcitylist =  array(
    'Mizoram' => array('Aizawl', 'Champhai', 'Kolasib', 'Lawngtlai', 'Lunglei', 'Mamit', 'Saiha', 'Serchhip'),
    'Nagaland' => array('Dimapur', 'Kohima', 'Mokokchung', 'Mon', 'Phek', 'Tuensang', 'Wokha', 'Zunheboto'),
    'Orissa' => array('Angul', 'Boudh', 'Bhadrak', 'Bolangir', 'Bargarh', 'Baleswar', 'Cuttack', 'Debagarh', 'Dhenkanal', 'Ganjam', 'Gajapati', 'Jharsuguda', 'Jajapur', 'Jagatsinghpur', 'Khordha', 'Kendujhar', 'Kalahandi', 'Kandhamal', 'Koraput', 'Kendrapara', 'Malkangiri', 'Mayurbhanj', 'Nabarangpur', 'Nuapada', 'Nayagarh', 'Puri', 'Rayagada', 'Sambalpur', 'Subarnapur', 'Sundargarh'),
    'Puducherry' => array('Karaikal', 'Mahe', 'Puducherry', 'Yanam')
);

foreach ($pcitylist as $key => $pcitylist1) {
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">';
        foreach ($pcitylist1 as $finalCity) {
            echo '<option value="' . $finalCity . '"' . (isset($_POST['pcity']) && $_POST['pcity'] == $finalCity ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $finalCity . '</option>';
        }
    echo '</optgroup>';
} 
?>
</select></td>
```

Comment: I didn't read your question, just because your code is so badly formated...

Comment: use "select multiple" and then values with $_post, those value with matches put selected code

Comment: formatting has been done and just waiting on peer review to approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use select with name pcity[] 
In this case in $_POST['pcity'] will array of selected value.
And you should [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) function  for check what item was select.

```
echo '<option value="' . $finalCity . '"' . (isset($_POST['pcity']) && in_array($finalCity, $_POST['pcity']) ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $finalCity . '</option>';
```